# Form validation onsubmit - trying to run a script upon successful validation fails in FF/IE, works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, onsubmit

I have a simple validation function on my HTML form and I'm trying to run a small script upon successfully submitting the form. It works just fine in Chrome but doesn't execute the JQuery stuff before returning true either in FF or IE. Why might this be?

Basically the JQuery replaces the < div > containing the input textarea with an informative text to prevent the user submitting another form until 5 seconds have passed and then switches back.

```
function validate() {

if (textarea.value.length < 1) {
return false;
}

$("#div_with_input_textarea").hide();
$("#div_with_informative_text").show();

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#div_with_input_textarea").show();
    $("#div_with_informative_text").hide();
    }
           , 5000);

return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "doesn't execute the jQuery stuff"?  In other words: 1) what is your expected result and 2) what are you actually seeing?

Comment: I mean my expected result is the way it's functioning in Google Chrome: If no text is input the form won't be submitted and nothing else needs to happen. Otherwise the form will be submitted and the jquery code will be executed in the same go. What I'm seeing in FF & IE is that the jquery code doesn't work at all - only the basic validation function is in effect - it either returns false or true but leaves the #div hiding/showing out of the function for some reason.

Comment: I see. Well, I don't see anything immediately wrong here. I believe it usually pays to be explicit in your property/method calls, so I would change `setTimeout` to `window.setTimeout`. I'm also not sure where the `textarea` variable is coming from, but I take it you have assigned that properly (since it works as you expect in Chrome). I think a good next step is for you to make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the problem so I and others can debug it.

Comment: Cheers for the quick replies Zach. I managed to get this working. You would have prolly had this fixed in a jiffy if I would have provided the HTML part as well :-) The problem lied in the if-statement. Chrome was fine with having only the input field's ID to count the chars in it. IE/FF required more. IE started to work when I added the form's ID ("form_name.textarea.value.length") and finally FF got my drift when I changed it to "document.forms["form_name"].textarea.value.length".

Comment: Thanks for following up, @user1564423. Glad to hear you got it working!

Comment: One more thing: could you re-type your last comment as an answer to your question and then accept that answer? That way anyone stumbling upon this question will see the solution easier.